# FSTAB on Debian 11 Mounts Drives in Read-Only Mode

Tags: linux, debian, mount, fstab

I installed MergerFS on a debian machine, and things seem to work. However, the drives end-up in read-only mode. How can I fix this?

```
/etc/fstab


/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST1000LM014-1EJ164_W770QH4A-part1 /mnt/disk1   ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST4000LM024-2AN17V_WCK4CN7A-part1 /mnt/disk2   ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 0
/mnt/disk* /mnt/storage fuse.mergerfs defaults,nonempty,allow_other,use_ino,cache.files=off,moveonenospc=true,dropcacheonclose=true,minfreespace=200G,fsname=mergerfs 0 0
```

When I run the following command, the read-only mode goes away until the next reboot

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /
```

Pertinent information

```
user@user:~$ ls -lha /mnt/
total 24K
drwxr-xr-x  6 root       root       4.0K Apr  4 08:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root       root       4.0K Apr  4 08:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x 18 root       root       4.0K Apr  4 08:59 disk1
drwxr-xr-x  3 user       user       4.0K Apr  4 08:59 disk2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root       4.0K Apr  4 08:33 manualdiskmounttest
drwxr-xr-x 18 root       root       4.0K Apr  4 08:59 storage
```

Comment: You are remounting `/` - but your `fstab` says the mergerfs is mounted on `/mnt/storage`?

Comment: @Panki Yes, I followed a MergeFS tutorial, which instructed me to do that. As to mounting `/`, I discovered empirically that that is what fixed the issue until the next reboot.